# Регулярные выражения при копировании файлов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Мало того, что я чуть менее чем наполовину соображаю в регулярках, так еще и усложнил в n-раз себе задачу! В тексте заменяются пути к файлам-картинкам на новые пути, кроме того, эти обновленные пути снова используются для копирования данных файлов. Пути я заменил так :

```
$text = preg_replace("#images/(.*)'#" , "/anotherDir/images/$1'",$text);
```

Может и коряво, но это работает. В следующих строках кода нужно файлы, участвовавшие в переименовании, скопировать в вышеуказанную директорию. Т.е. нужно как-то сохранить все вот эти $1 для дальнейшего использования. Я вообще теряюсь. Какую функцию применить. То ли preg_match_all то ли... в общем,  подскажите, кто может! Хотя бы ход решения.

Comment: есть такие функции как [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.dirname.php) и [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php), а так-же [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: @eicto, это прекрасные функции, но они мне не подойдут. Файлов штук 200, а нужно копировать только те, которые были упомянуты в $text

Comment: Ответ @klopp делает то что необходимо, но лучше изменить регулярное выражение на примерно такое:  

    /images/(.+\.(?:jpg|png|bmp|gif))$
просто для безопасности, иначе можете увидеть нечто вроде:  

    /images/../index.php
в том самом тексте в котором надо преобразовывать пути.

Comment: @ReinRaus, вы правы. Только я сильно не заморачивался по поводу защиты, это кагбэ страничка для кагбэ администрирования, то - спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так можно:

```
function replace_and_move( $m )
{
    // ну или не переименовывать, а где-то сохранить значения:
    rename( $m[1].$m[2], '/anotherDir/images/'.$m[2] );
    return '/anotherDir/images/'.$m[2];
}
$text = preg_replace_callback("#(images/)(.*)#" , 'replace_and_move', $text);
```

Comment: @klopp,спасибо за ответ. А вот я только что догадался - добавил еще одно регулярное выражение  preg_match_all("#images/([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)'#",$text,$matches).  Т.е. в $matches теперь эти вот имена файлов. Так можно? )) Просто это работает, но регулярок уже две!

Comment: @klopp, вы не только посоветовали, но и дали полное решение. Спасибо. К тому же теперь я знаю в каком направлении двигаться дальше!